# Combining two shapefiles using common attribute

Tags: shapefile, r, merge, sp

I have two shapefiles `"sf1"` and `"sf2"` for same area.

- `"sf1"` is population data for year 2015 and has 6 variables.
  [image]
- `"sf2"` is population data for year 2010 and has 5 variables.
  [image]

Both have one common attribute `"GEOID"`. I want to get a combined layer with 8 variables (6 from 2015 and the 2 (variable and value) from 2010).

How can I combined the two shapefiles using the common attribute `"GEOID"`? I tried merging them.

```
sf3 <- merge(sf1, sf2)
```

It merges the two layers to give me 11 variables. This is not what I want. I want to join the attribute tables for the two layers and get one of the common attributes.

Comment: are the geometries the same between them? that is, "GEOID" 1 in sf1 and "GEOID" 1 in sf2 are the same shape?  if so, you may be able to ignore the geometry in one of the shapefiles altogether and just do what ESRI  calls "Join Field" it will append one or more attributes from table B to onto table A based on a common attribute or in this case, a "GEOID".

Comment: Yes, the geometrics (GEOID) are same in both sf. What is the similar function in R that does the "join" in ArcGIS? I tried inner_join, which gives me the error as Error: y should not have class sf; for spatial joins, use st_join. I tried st_join but got 229 obs. of 10 variables. I just want same # of variables with 8 variables.

Comment: I think you do want dplyr::inner_join() but it is unhappy because it can't cope with both objects having geometry (and you have said the geometry for each GEOID is the same in each object). To solve that use dplyr::select() on the 2nd object to select only the non geometry columns. More general info on joining and select here : https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/attr.html#vector-attribute-joining

Comment: I'm sorry I gave an ESRI solution; I didn't notice that you had tagged this questions as being in r I unfortunately do not know any r

Comment: Thank you Andy, I tried the way similar to what you said by changing just the second object into dataframe and joining it to the first sf object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you state, you are trying to join only the non-spatial data; but `sf` standard doesn't allow two geometry columns; `dplyr::select()` for the non-spatial columns will fail, because, as stated in `sf` manual, geometries are *sticky*, so first you have to convert to `as.data.frame()` and then select off the geometry column with `select(-geometry)`

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

geometry = st_sfc(st_point(1:2), st_point(3:4))
# a will be the common variable
sf1 = st_sf(geoid=3:4, v_2010 = c(483,567), geometry)
sf2 = st_sf(geoid=3:4, v_2015 = c(484,570),  geometry)

left_join(sf1, sf2, by = "geoid") # throws an error, sf objects cannot have 2 geometries
left_join(sf1, sf2 %>% as.data.frame() %>% select(-geometry), by = "geoid")

Simple feature collection with 2 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 2 xmax: 3 ymax: 4
CRS:            NA
  geoid v_2010 v_2015    geometry
1     3    483    484 POINT (1 2)
2     4    567    570 POINT (3 4)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the way similar to what you said by changing just the second object into dataframe and joining it to the first sf object.